# Prepared Statements- Execute Batch, whole batch fails even though one row has error

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, batch-processing

I have a problem that when I have a duplicate row in a batch, my execute batch fails for this row but the problem is the rest of the insert statements are not executed. I use Oracle SQL driver major version JDBC 4.

How can I assure you that at least the error-free rows are executed and just the data row with errors is not inserted?

```
  conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    try {
    PreparedStatement testStatement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into EW_JOBS.jhi_job_history values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" );





    testStatement.setInt(1, 4477443);
    testStatement.setInt(2, 4477443);
    testStatement.setDate(3, null);
    testStatement.setString(4, null);
    testStatement.setString(5, null);
    testStatement.setString(6, null);
    testStatement.setString(7, null);
    testStatement.setString(8, null);
    testStatement.setString(9, null);
    testStatement.setString(10, null);
    testStatement.addBatch();
    testStatement.setInt(1, 4477444);
    testStatement.setInt(2, 4477444);
    testStatement.setDate(3, null);
    testStatement.setString(4, null);
    testStatement.setString(5, null);
    testStatement.setString(6, null);
    testStatement.setString(7, null);
    testStatement.setString(8, null);
    testStatement.setString(9, null);
    testStatement.setString(10, null);

    testStatement.addBatch();

    testStatement.setInt(1, 4477443);
    testStatement.setInt(2, 4477443);
    testStatement.setDate(3, null);
    testStatement.setString(4, null);
    testStatement.setString(5, null);
    testStatement.setString(6, null);
    testStatement.setString(7, null);
    testStatement.setString(8, null);
    testStatement.setString(9, null);
    testStatement.setString(10, null);

    testStatement.addBatch();

    testStatement.setInt(1, 4477445);
    testStatement.setInt(2, 4477445);
    testStatement.setDate(3, null);
    testStatement.setString(4, null);
    testStatement.setString(5, null);
    testStatement.setString(6, null);
    testStatement.setString(7, null);
    testStatement.setString(8, null);
    testStatement.setString(9, null);
    testStatement.setString(10, null);
    testStatement.addBatch();

    testStatement.setInt(1, 4477446);
    testStatement.setInt(2, 4477446);
    testStatement.setDate(3, null);
    testStatement.setString(4, null);
    testStatement.setString(5, null);
    testStatement.setString(6, null);
    testStatement.setString(7, null);
    testStatement.setString(8, null);
    testStatement.setString(9, null);
    testStatement.setString(10, null);

    testStatement.addBatch();



    testStatement.executeBatch();
    conn.commit();
    conn.close();
    }
    catch (BatchUpdateException e) {


       System.out.println("update counts value is : " +e.getUpdateCounts());

    }
```

Comment: Please post your code. Did you disable auto commit?

Comment: Originally yes, but it also does not work with autocommit true. Ideally I would like that the Batch processing would continue even after one row has an error, in this case a duplicate. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes, this is the way batches work. There is no workaround (other than not using batched inserts)

Comment: Sorry, I had misread your question. The exact behaviour of whether a failure stops the rest of the batch, or if it continues with the remaining statements is driver-specific. JDBC allows a driver to choose one option, but requires it to consistently apply that choice. Oracle chose the 'stop on first error' approach.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Is there a work around for this? I believe not.